# Post large files to heroku with Python

Tags: python, rest, heroku, python-requests

I'm creating a python script that will post audio files to an API. It's mostly working; however, the application is on Heroku and large files seem to be getting nabbed by heroku's memory limit. I tried using multipart/form-data, but it seems like that's not enough. I'm getting 503 errors for anything over about 5 minutes.

```
import requests
import os
import glob
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder

token = 'XXXX'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
base_url = 'https://test.com/api/'

for file in glob.glob("*.mp3"):
    files = MultipartEncoder(fields={'file': (file, open(file, "rb"), 'audio/mpeg')})
    audio_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'Content-Type': files.content_type}
    add_file = requests.post(base_url, headers=audio_headers, data=files)
```

Comment: I think the 503 is actually what Heroku returns for your application when it hasn't responded in a certain period of time. I'm not sure it's a file-size limit. I don't know how to work around this, perhaps you should contact Heroku support to see if they have any strategies for handling this.

Comment: Thanks :) You've been very helpful today.

Comment: It seems like the problem might have been my internet connection because I tried running it again this morning at my office and didn't have any problems.

Comment: Well that's truly bizarre. If  you can reproduce it, shoot me an email.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has a 30 second limit for all requests. Larger files will certainly exceed that period and thus the request times out. The only solution is to post to a 3rd party storage directly from the browser (e.g. Amazon S3), and then send a request to heroku with the location of the uploaded data. Using a background process you'll be able to download the file and process it however you want.

Comment: According to [heroku's limits docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits):
HTTP requests have an initial 30 second window in which the web process must return response data (either the completed response or some amount of response data to indicate that the process is active). Processes that do not send response data within the initial 30-second window will see an H12 error in their logs.
After the initial response, each byte sent (either from the client or from your app process) resets a rolling 55 second window.